# Why does my random trajectory systematic biais in angle?

Tags: r, distribution, angle

I have a tracjectory in 2D (list of x,y positions).
I am trying to measure the angles of the motion between consecutive points.

So I calculate the scalar product of the two consecutive vectors, divide by the vector norms, and this gives me the cosinus of the angles I am looking for.

However, when I generate totally **random trajectories** (by generating random `x` and random `y`), I always have a high number of **`cos` results very close to `-1`**, or `1`. While I was expecting to have all cos between -1 and 1 equally likely.

Here's my code to generate the trajectories (after correction from the comments below), and calculate the cosinus:

```
cost = c()

t = seq(0,500,0.5)
x = 1*runif( length(t),-1,1 )
y = 1*runif( length(t),-1,1 )
x = cumsum(x)
y = cumsum(y)

step = 1
dstep = 2

for ( j in 1:((length(t)-dstep)))
{
    x1 = x[j+step]-x[j]
    y1 = y[j+step]-y[j]
    x2 = x[j+dstep]-x[j+step]
    y2 = y[j+dstep]-y[j+step]

    n1 = sqrt( x1*x1 + y1*y1 )
    n2 = sqrt( x2*x2 + y2*y2 )

    if ( (n1*n2) > 0 )
    {
        scal = x1*x2 + y1*y2
        cost = c( cost, scal/(n1*n2) )
        #print( paste(n1, " ", n2, " ", n1*n2, " ", scal, " ", x1, " ", x2, " ", scal/(n1*n2), sep="") )
    }

}
```

When i look at the histogram of the `cost` results, I always have a high number of `cost` very close to -1 and 1:

```
> hist(cost, plot=F)
$breaks
 [1] -1.00 -0.95 -0.90 -0.85 -0.80 -0.75 -0.70 -0.65 -0.60 -0.55 -0.50 -0.45
[13] -0.40 -0.35 -0.30 -0.25 -0.20 -0.15 -0.10 -0.05  0.00  0.05  0.10  0.15
[25]  0.20  0.25  0.30  0.35  0.40  0.45  0.50  0.55  0.60  0.65  0.70  0.75
[37]  0.80  0.85  0.90  0.95  1.00

$counts
 [1] 108  43  32  20  22  21  19  20  19  17  16  19   8  19  23  17  15  10  18
[20]  22  15  19  14  15  18  16  21  11  18  20  16  35  23  24  24  20  23  33
[39]  37 107
```

Any idea where I'm wrong or why it should do that ?

Thanks for help

Comment: I think it makes sense given your generative model. Your point distribution is a square centered at (0.5, 0.5). The next point is always more likely to be towards the center (and the other side of the center), so sharp quasi u-turns are likely and the distribution of your cosinus reflects that. You can see all the sharp turns with `plot(head(x, n = 20), head(y, n = 20), type = "b")`, due to the underlying distribution of the points.

Comment: If you want a random walk, you can generate random moves, not random positions. In other words, center your distributions (e.g. use `rnom` or `runif(min=-1, max=1)` and take the cumsum of `x` and `y` as your trajectories.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried it, but I still don't have a random distribution of angles. I tried to change the generation of the random points to `x = runif( length(t),-1,1 ) ;
y = runif( length(t),-1,1 );
x = cumsum(x);
y = cumsum(y)`, but there's still a strong biais. Now both for -1 and 1

Comment: The probabilty of the angle should be uniform with this generation model no ?

Comment: And generating with `rnorm` and taking `cumsum` afterwards doesn't change the results (again, lot of `cost` close to 1 or -1)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback !

Comment: Actually this distribution of the cos is what you get when angles are uniformly distributed! Consider `hist(cos(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 2*pi)))`. So it's working as expected. `cos` just moves quickly over 0 and slowly over 1 and -1. See `plot(cos, from = 0, to = 2*pi)`.

Comment: Oh! indeed! Great, thanks a lot !

Comment: And there is explanation of it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153339/distribution-of-cosine-of-uniformly-random-variables  Makes sense now !

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else meet this problem, here's the summary of the solution from the comments:

> Actually this distribution of the cos is what you get when angles are uniformly distributed! Consider hist(cos(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 2*pi))). So it's working as expected. cos just moves quickly over 0 and slowly over 1 and -1. See plot(cos, from = 0, to = 2*pi).

Which is indeed explained there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153339/distribution-of-cosine-of-uniformly-random-variables

The solution is thus that it is normal to have more values of cosinus close to 1 and -1 from a distribution of totally random angles.